# What is the recommended way to persist (pickle) custom sklearn pipelines?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle, pyinstaller

I have built an [sklearn pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) that combines a standard support vector regression component with some custom transformers that create features. This pipeline is then put into an object which is trained and then pickled ([this seems to be the recommended way](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html)). The unpickled object is used to make predictions.

For distribution, this is turned into an executable file with [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).

When I call the unpickled regression object from a unit test, it works fine.

However, when I attempt to use the PyInstaller binary to make predictions, I get a long [stack trace](https://gist.github.com/RokoMijic/83f73eb260481f7eadcde10b9f297999) that ends with:

> ```
> module = loader.load_module(fullname)   File "messagestream.pxd", line 5, in init scipy.optimize._trlib._trlib ImportError: No module named 'scipy._lib.messagestream'
> ```

This feels like some kind of pickling error, probably due to the interaction of pickling with pyinstaller. How can I refactor my code so that my custom pipeline runs just as easily and robustly as a standard sklearn regressor after unpickling?

Comment: are you pickling your model with joblib??

Comment: No, I am pickling with pickle, though I have also tried joblib and dill to no avail.

Comment: Someone else has the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47055712/error-when-executing-compiled-file-no-module-named-scipy-lib-messagestream

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, after some googling around it seems to be the case that the root cause is not pickling, it is simply a pyinstaller "hidden imports" issue, but for some reason it only shows up when pickling (don't ask me why).

The following solved the immediate issue for me: edit the `.spec` file to add the following hidden import with `Scipy`:

```
 hiddenimports=['scipy._lib.messagestream']
```

I also needed some other hidden imports related to other libraries

```
 hiddenimports=['sklearn.neighbors.typedefs',
                'scipy._lib.messagestream',
                'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas'   ]
```

Comment: thanks for the trick. I didn’t have to deal with that in may 2017. Is this a bug in the new version ?

Comment: Works with py2exe too.

Comment: Where can i find the .spec file? I've been looking in the .whl and the evironment I can find it in neither of those.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone just wants to do this via CLI argument instead of through the .spec file as presented in Roko's answer, this is the syntax:

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import scipy._lib.messagestream --onefile your_python_file_here.py
```