# Error when executing compiled file " No module named 'scipy._lib.messagestream' "after using pyinstaller

Tags: python, scipy, pyinstaller

i am trying to complile our code https://bitbucket.org/OES_muni/massiveoes using **pyinstaller** after upgrading from python 2.7 to 3.6 and moving to scipy 1.0.0 at same time. I am working on 64bit win7 machine. The program itself runs fine, pyinstaller runs without errors but when i try to run the build exe file it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "massiveOES\GUI.py", line 23, in <module>   File "c:\users\petr\envs\py1\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)   File "massiveOES\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>   File "c:\users\petr\envs\py1\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)   File "massiveOES\FHRSpectra.py", line 1, in <module>   File "c:\users\petr\envs\py1\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)   File "massiveOES\spectrum.py", line 3, in <module>   File "c:\users\petr\envs\py1\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)   File "site-packages\scipy\optimize\__init__.py", line 241, in <module>   File "c:\users\petr\envs\py1\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)   File "site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 28, in <module>   File "c:\users\petr\envs\py1\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)   File "site-packages\scipy\optimize\_trustregion_krylov.py", line 2, in <module>   File "c:\users\petr\envs\py1\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)   File "site-packages\scipy\optimize\_trlib\__init__.py", line 1, in <module> File "c:\users\petr\envs\py1\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 714, in load_module
    module = loader.load_module(fullname)   File "messagestream.pxd", line 5, in init scipy.optimize._trlib._trlib ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy._lib.messagestream' [2128] Failed to execute script GUI
```

Comment: I am having the same issue with PyInstaller... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47040099/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-persist-pickle-custom-sklearn-pipelines

Answer (score 18, accepted):

OK, the following solved the immediate issue for me: edit the pyinstaller `.spec` file to add the following hidden import with `Scipy`:

```
 hiddenimports=['scipy._lib.messagestream']
```

See [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47040099/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-persist-pickle-custom-sklearn-pipelines/47071268#47071268) for more.

Comment: thanks for the trick. I didn’t have to deal with that in may 2017. Is this a bug in the new version ?

Comment: looks solved in next release? Discussion here: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2987