# Using pyinstaller to package python program and there is a "NoModuleFoundError"

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I use pyinstaller to package my python program into an executable program(exe).

my programs versions:

Pyinstaller :3.3.1

Python :3.6.1
Windows:10-10.0.16299-SP0

---

I can run the data_processing_gui.py file with the command "python data_processing_gui.py" in my command-line window without any errors.

---

I used this command to package my python program (which its name is data_processing_gui.py):

```
pyinstaller -F -p C:\Users\fanyu\Anaconda3\Lib;C:\Users\fanyu\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages;C:\Users\fanyu\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin;C:\Users\fanyu\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pydicom;C:\Users\fanyu\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\radiomics;C:\Users\fanyu\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pywt;C:\Users\fanyu\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pywt\_extensions;C:\Users\fanyu\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow;C:\Users\fanyu\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\SimpleITK;C:\Users\fanyu\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PIL;C:\Users\fanyu\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas;C:\Users\fanyu\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\nrrd;C:\Users\fanyu\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy -i C:\Users\fanyu\Desktop\work\package\image\doctor.ico data_processing_gui.py
```

---

There is no error when I run code above in windows' command-line window, but when I run the target program(data_progressing_gui.exe), there is a `ModuleNotFoundError`, and the error information is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "data_processing_gui.py",
> line 12, in    File
> "c:\users\fanyu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
> line 631, in exec_module
> exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)   File "site-packages\radiomics_*init*_.py", line 15, in    File
> "c:\users\fanyu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
> line 631, in exec_module
> exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)   File "site-packages\radiomics\imageoperations.py", line 6, in 
> File
> "c:\users\fanyu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
> line 631, in exec_module
> exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)   File "site-packages\pywt_*init*_.py", line 17, in    File
> "c:\users\fanyu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
> line 631, in exec_module
> exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)   File "site-packages\pywt_functions.py", line 17, in    File
> "c:\users\fanyu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
> line 714, in load_module
> module = loader.load_module(fullname)   File "pywt/_extensions/_pywt.pyx", line 1, in init pywt._extensions._pywt
> (pywt_extensions_pywt.c:31281) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
> 'pywt._extensions._cwt' [7564] Failed to execute script
> data_processing_gui

It seems like the program can't find the specified package path (pywt._extensions._cwt), however, I've added the path in the pyinstaller's parameter list.

At first, I thought maybe there was something wrong with my pyinstaller, so I tried to reinstall it. Then I write a simple python program to test it, it runs correctly.

I've tried a lot but just can't solve it, so I am here to ask for help,I will appreciate it if anyone can give me any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find a solution for my problem in the answers to the following question [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47607315/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pandas-libs-tslibs-timedeltas)

I can't explain why but it does solve my problem.

The solution is:
After generating the ".spec" file using pyinstaller,add the missing module into the ".spec" file at "hiddenimport=[]",like this:

```
hiddenimport=["pywt","pywt._estentions._cwt"]
```

Then use this file to generate your exe file:

```
pyinstaller my.spec
```